# Disable cmd-R for executing scripts in Google Apps Script Editor on Mac

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-apps-script, editor

I've just started to use the Google Apps Scripts Editor on Chrome on a Mac. The good people at Google added a shortcut for quickly running scripts, which on Windows is ctrl-R, and probably doesn't conflict with anything. Then they translated it to cmd-R on Mac, which globally makes sense. As a Mac user however, I'm used to using cmd-R to reload pages (as compared to F5 on Windows). The google shortcut takes precedence, meaning that each time I hit cmd-R to simply force updating the page (because it sometimes help to reload the page), it launches the script I'm viewing. I'm worried it may at some point execute a script that I'm not intending to execute at that particular time.

Is there any way to disable the google shortcut? I'm perfectly fine having to go and click the arrow, but I'm not fine risking launching a script when I don't mean to.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to disable the shortcut keys in Google Apps Script. However, you can add a confirmation dialog box in your script to add extra layer of protection from running your script accidentally.

### Example:

**Code:**

```
function myFunction() {
 var confirm = Browser.msgBox('Are you sure you want to execute the script?', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
 if(confirm == 'ok'){
   //insert your code here
 }
}
```

**Dialog Box:**

[image]

### Reference:

- [msgBox(prompt, buttons](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/browser#msgboxprompt,-buttons)

Comment: Thanks, while it's disappointing that there's no actual solution for the conflict, this is definitely a start. I was hoping/trying to be able to have that check run globally prior to running any function by putting it at the top-level, it gets executed before any function call but I haven't yet found a way to interrupt the script execution (`return` doesn't work from outside a function). It's starting to look dirty. Maybe I'll just have to live with adding this check at the start of every function.

Answer (score 0):

Following @Nikko's suggestion I'm displaying a dialog box when the script is started (i.e. top-level), and when the answer is "cancel" I simply wait (`Utilities.sleep()`) for 5 minutes, and then again. This prevents the function from being executed until the script would be killed automatically, but more adequately it keeps the script execution dialog box displayed, in which you can choose to cancel the execution. So you don't have to wait 5 minutes, just click "cancel" while the script is doing nothing. Again, dirty, but works for me.

```
if(Browser.msgBox("Are you sure you want to run this script?", Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL) == 'cancel') {
  Utilities.sleep(300000)
  Utilities.sleep(300000) // just to prevent accidental execution in the last split-second
}
```